# jQuery Scroll To How to use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I use [jQuery](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)

to this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#grid" class="scrollto">Grid System</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tooltips" class="scrollto">Tooltips</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tables" class="scrollto">Tables</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#carousel" class="scrollto">Carousel</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#thumbnails" class="scrollto">Thumbnails</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#forms" class="scrollto">Forms</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rxn04stn/1/)

How can it also highlight the active div selected? (ul li a)

Comment: you dont't need js for that just a div with a id and a link that points to that id

Comment: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo - I am using this jQuery plugin here to do a smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion would be, first to give id's to the links:

`<a href="#tables" id="link1">Tables</a>`

and then use:

`$('#link1').scrollTo(document.getElementById('tables'), 800);`

as the documentation mentions.

Link to documentation and demos:

> http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: that would be a lot of codes. Can you show me a demo from here: https://jsfiddle.net/rxn04stn/1/

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you want to scroll to the href on the links, in jQuery you could do this simply with your current setup, without scrollTo which seems redundant to me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //ready
    $(".scrollTo").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();//don't execute click event (Actually going to anchor)
        var element = $(this);
        var elementOffsetTop = $(element.attr("href").offset().top;
        $(body).scrollTop(offset);
    })
});
```

Alternatively, if you want an animation, replace

```
$(body).scrollTop(offset);
```

with

```
$(body).animate({scrollTop: offset}, 500);
```

This, would of course make all your ".scrolltop" links work straight away, without libraries besides jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

***Jquery animate():***

You can achieve this using the jquery animate(). Use the `scrollTop` and set the property likewise:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
```

If you are looking to scroll to a specific target, then modify the `scrollTop` property likewise: *(**You will have to add an ID or class to your nav ul**)*

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#targetID").scrollTop() }, 1000);
```

jQuery animate [docs](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtisanBay/gx78ucvc/3/)

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, it comes with a plugin [ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).

Or try this code.

```
$('#collapse-here .nav li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(thisUrl).offset().top }, 1000);
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
    $(this).parents('li').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
});
```

See Updated CODE - https://jsfiddle.net/rxn04stn/12/